# Can java.net.ConnectException for Spring AMQP Listener Container can be handled?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

If the Rabbitmq Node is Down and we start Rabbitmq Listener Container so it loops for **infinite Times** until it gets Connected to Rabbitmq Node.So how we can stop this infinite trying by Listener Container if it not gets Connected to Rabbitmq Node ?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `Listener Container` failedEvent, which is emitted as;

```
 private void logException(Throwable t) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()
                    || !(t instanceof AmqpConnectException  || t instanceof CancelledException)) {
                logger.warn(
                        " raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it",
                        t);
            }
            else {
                logger.warn(" raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. "
                        + "Exception summary: " + t);
            }
            publishFailedEvent(" raised exception, attempting restart", false, t);
        }
```

So, you can listen for those events and stop your application when some condition is reached.

Comment: I am Using XML Configuration File , so where to add this method ?

Comment: Create a class 'FailureEventListener' which implements 'ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerFailedEvent>' and add the above code in it

Comment: This feature is not available in Spring version 1.4.5 ,please you can tell a way which is available in this version ?

Comment: You should upgrade. 1.4.x is very old.